# webdriver 2.20 with threads

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to webdriver 2.20 based testing code with threads in java. for some reason new FirefoxDriver() throws exception.

Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.20.0', revision: '16008', time: '2012-02-27 19:03:04'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

This happens only if I use threads. I run the same code without using threads then it works perfectly fine.

How can I fix this ?

Best,
Rohan

Comment: That's the odd exception we see sometimes. Mainly - try Selenium 2.21.0, it improved FirefoxDriver stability by a lot. Then please, show us the threads code with driver instantiation.

Comment: Slanec, This got resolved. There was a problem with the place where I was creating the firefoxDriver object. After I placed the instantiation in the run() method , it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose use [RemoteWebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#remotewebdriver) and launch local [selenium server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). It's able to manage ports and launch several WebDriver instances at the same time.
WebDriver initialisation should look like :

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                            new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), 
                            DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```